# Send form data in Django using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have `ajax` call inside external js file as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Contact form
    let contact_button = $("#contact-button");
    contact_button.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let contact_name = $("#contact-name");
        let contact_email = $("#contact-email");
        let contact_message = $("#contact-message");

        let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/main/contact-us/',
            data: {
                email: contact_email.val(),
                name: contact_name.val(),
                message: contact_message.val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                hideSpinner();
                resetForm();
                contact_form_success()
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                showSpinner();
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                hideSpinner();
                let errors = null;
                if (typeof data.responseJSON !== "undefined") {
                    errors = data.responseJSON;
                }
                contact_form_error(errors)
            }
        })
    });

});
```

And in my view is as follows:

```
def contact_us(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact_us_form = ContactUsForm(request.POST)
        if contact_us_form.is_valid():

            name = contact_us_form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = contact_us_form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = contact_us_form.cleaned_data['message']

            try:
                subject = '[WEB] A customer sent you a message'
                body = render_to_string('contact_email.html', {'name': name, 'email': email, 'message': message})
                from_email = 'web@bemiddelingscenter.com'
                to_emails = MAIN_MAIL

                msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from_email, to_emails)
                msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
                msg.mixed_subtype = 'related'

                msg.send()
                return HttpResponse(status=200)
            except:
                return HttpResponse(status=404)
        else:
            data = {
                "email_error_exists": len(contact_us_form['email'].errors) > 0,
                "name_error_exists": len(contact_us_form['name'].errors) > 0,
                "message_error_exists": len(contact_us_form['message'].errors) > 0,
            }
            return JsonResponse(data, status=404)
```

And in my html template I have the code as follows:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input id="contact-name" class="form-control g-brd-none g-brd-bottom g-brd-white g-brd-primary--focus g-color-white g-bg-transparent g-placeholder-gray-light-v5 rounded-0 g-py-13 g-px-0 mb-2"
               type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <input id="contact-email" class="form-control g-brd-none g-brd-bottom g-brd-white g-brd-primary--focus g-color-white g-bg-transparent g-placeholder-gray-light-v5 rounded-0 g-py-13 g-px-0 mb-2"
               type="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-4">
        <textarea id="contact-message"
                class="form-control g-brd-none g-brd-bottom g-brd-white g-brd-primary--focus g-color-white g-bg-transparent g-placeholder-gray-light-v5 g-resize-none rounded-0 g-py-13 g-px-0 mb-5"
                rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button id="contact-button"
            class="btn u-btn-primary g-bg-secondary g-color-primary g-color-white--hover g-bg-primary--hover g-font-weight-600 g-font-size-12 g-rounded-30 g-py-15 g-px-35"
            type="submit"
            role="button"
            title="{% trans "Send message" %}">
        <span id="btn-send-initial">{% trans "Send message" %}</span>
        <span id="btn-spinner-sending" class="hidden">
            {% trans "Sending" %} <img class="sending-spinner" src="/assets/img/loading.gif" style="width: 20px;" alt="{% trans "Loading" %}"
                                       title="{% trans "Loading" %}"/>
        </span>
    </button>



</form>
```

The `urls.py` in main app is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^main/', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # Languages
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'), name='set_language'),
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict, name='javascript-catalog'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And in main app urls.py are as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', index, name="index"),
    url(r'^contact-us/', contact_us, name="contact_us"),
]
```

But the problem is whenever I click on button send I get the success message and the email is not sent.

Any idea?

Comment: to_emails = MAIN_MAIL, whats that line is

Comment: `["my-email@gmail.com", ]` . But if I add `pdb.set_trace()` after `def contact_us(request):` it does not stop. I just like that it not goes to `contact_us` at all

Comment: it's may be due to wrong url map  url(r'^$', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^main/', include('main.urls')),

Comment: @amankumar What do I need to use? I tried `url: '/main/contact-us/'` and `url: '/contact-us/',` , but the same problem.

Comment: as @aman kumar say in your index url regex you must close regex with end of regex. django url engine handle your request with index view and you not view anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', index, name="index"),
   url(r'^contact-us/$', contact_us, name="contact_us"),
]
```

Comment: try this one. Before that can you  just console log in ajax success. what you are getting